# Android List item background image not stretching

Tags: android, listview, background

I have a textview I'm using for each row of a ListView. It's XML looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView android:id="@+id/celltitle"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:text="Filler Text" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/cell_bg" android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp" android:textSize="18dp" android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" />
```

Where cell_bg is a .9.png I have created. In all of the Graphical Layouts the image seems to stretch correctly. However in the actual ListView it shows the width of the .9.png or the size of the font. How can I make the background image stretch the entire width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple solution, it was my listview that wasn't set to fill_parent for it's width. It had nothing to do with the listitem.